# Conditional Probability with hidden variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If we have $A$ which is dependent on $B$,$C$, and $D$, (all binary: True / False) then:
$P(A=T,B=T,C=T) = P(A=T,B=T,C=T,D=T) + P(A=T,B=T,C=T,D=F)$.

Why is it incorrect if we apply the same logic to the following conditional probability:

$P(A=T| B=T,C=T) = P(A=T|B=T,C=T,D=T) + P(A=T|B=T,C=T,D=F)$

I kind of see why it's incorrect, but can we show it mathematically?

Comment: First, check that you understand why the first equation holds: $P(E_1 \cup E_2) = P(E_1) + P(E_2)$ for *disjoint* events $E_1$ and $E_2$. For the second equation, write out the definitions of the conditional probabilities, i.e. $P(A=T \mid B=T, C=T, D=T) = P(A=T, B=T, C=T, D=T) / P(B=T, C=T, D=T)$.

Comment: "*but can we show it mathematically*"  Yes, by giving an explicit counterexample.  We don't need to explain *why* the logic is wrong or how to fix the logic.  We just need to prove that it is wrong.

Comment: The two sides of the vertical bar in a conditional probability are very different. On the left are the things whose probabilities we are after. On the right are the things we know. Qualitatively, these are two very different roles, so it should be no surprise that rules that hold on one side don't hold on the other.